# Wrong list size on deserialize list in xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<renditions type="array">
    <rendition>
        <id>1</id>
    </rendition>
    <rendition>
        <id>2</id>
    </rendition>
</renditions>
```

this. is my mapped Rendition class :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "rendition")
public class Rendition {

    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String id;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

To deserialize my xml I do this :

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);

List<Rendition> renditions = mapper.readValue(inputStream,
                TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Rendition.class));

renditions.stream().map(ReflectionToStringBuilder::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And I don't understand why I get 3 item instead of 2:

```
Output:
Rendition@38093ffe[id=<null>]
Rendition@4713b631[id=1]
Rendition@7a0d2c80[id=2]
```

So I want to know why I get a null item in first place, because  the two other items are good.

I used jackson 2.10.1 version.

After many tests, if I delete attribut type="array", it's working. But life is not easy and the xml that I deserialize provided by an external service.

Is it possible to solve my problems without make String replacement or create Renditions class (that only have a rendition list)?

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell in ticket, I use 2.10.1 version

Comment: That's strange but for the same version I have only two elements printed on output.

Comment: I test again, and I have 3 items, I supposed that it's due to renditions tag. I guess...

Comment: @Michal it's my mistake, I forget to give complete example, I did'nt have <renditions> but <renditions type="array>, I update my message.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to create `Renditions` class with `List<Rendition>` property.